# AWS SDK C++ Unable to use in vs projectUE4

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I want to use AWS SDK C++ in my unreal project. I successfully created  "out of source build" of the library by cmake now  Will you please guide me how to use sdk in UE project .Docs on Amazon are quiet confusing.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you already tried, what errors you got, etc.

Comment: I have cloned AWS SDK C++ From https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp and built it in a folder using cmake commands----" cmake <path-to-root-of-this-source-code> -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" then this "
msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release".Now sdk is build and ready to be used in one of my unreal project but  how to get this library to be used in my UE4 project .Static linking???????